# limit results returned core results web part

Tags: search, search-results

is there an option how to limit the number of results returned? F.e. I have a req where client want to show only 50 of tasks.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

So I ended up with restricting number of results in xslt. I created c# xslt extension function which is responsible for creating navigation with the same structure as oob navigation. In this navigation I restrict render the 'Next' links that can lead user to next page with another results. To user it look like the search reached end but anyway there are still results. I will post my code later because I have to clean naming.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the **List View Threshold** on the View definition. In your list just head over to *"Modify View"* and set how many items you would like to be displayed.

Comment: hi, on core results web part?

Comment: With Core Results you mean the search? Or a List View WebPart?

Comment: yes, search :) sorry if i do not express the problem enough

Comment: You can either set it in the WebPart properties of the Core Result WebPart or you can change the `"<xsl:param name="MaximumRows">` in the underlying XSLT to whatever you want.

Comment: probably i do not express the problem again enough, sorry for that. The xslt does not have the param MaximumRows either the web part. I need to change the total rows/results returned (eg show only top 50), not just the number of results per page. Also i need to preserve pagination.

Answer (score 0):

In your CoreResultsWebPart, you can override the ConfigureDataSourceProperties method like this:

```
protected override void ConfigureDataSourceProperties()
{
    base.ConfigureDataSourceProperties();

    CoreResultsDatasource dataSource = this.DataSource as CoreResultsDatasource;

    // setting the value to 50 as per your example.
    dataSource.ResultsPerPage = 50;
}
```

Comment: thanks for response : ) however i needed to override all the result returned, for example from 1000 results show only top 50 on 5 pages with paging 10

Comment: Ah -> slightly different than your question.  No worries, you could look at the HighestResultPage property of the CoreResultsWebPart, but I've never specified a value for that property & I'm not sure if that would work for you.

Comment: well i first tried it but the behavior was not as expected. it shows you next page link but when you visit it, the ugly message pops up that you are trying to visit more than is allowed :)